# Visual Studio unexpectedly closed when I tried to open specific files of Mission Planner at design time

Tags: c#, mission-planner

I followed the instructions in  Mission Planner GitHub page. However, Visual Studio failed (*I mean it froze, then closed without any alerts*) when I tried to open up some specific files, and based on the limited messages I got from Event Viewer, I found that it's the issue of a control called HUD, which is in the `MissionPlanner.Controls` project.

The message from event viewer:

[image: the message from event viewer]

Additionally, for testing purposes, I also tried to add an new HUD control to a form that doesn't have the control, and it threw a `MissingMethodException`, which is different from what I saw on Event Viewer. To sum up, I got different exceptions from the same file.

The error message when I tried to add a new HUD:

[image: the error message when I tried to add a new HUD]

However, after all these exceptions, the project can be built and it works fine at runtime.

I checked the versions of the dependencies for the `MissionPlanner.Controls` project, but I didn't notice anything wrong or unusual. Then, for the first exception, I commented out some code in the Dispose method in HUD.cs. Though the design pages that include HUDs still don't show properly, at least Visual Studio no longer closes unexpectedly.

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        log.Info("HUD Dispose");

        if (opengl)
        {
            foreach (character texid in _texture)
            {
                //if (texid != null && texid.gltextureid != 0)
                //GL.DeleteTexture(texid.gltextureid);
            }

            this._texture = new character[_texture.Length];

            foreach (character texid in charDict.Values)
            {
                //if (texid.gltextureid != 0)
                //GL.DeleteTexture(texid.gltextureid);
            }
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

As for the second exception, I thought that it might be an issue caused by a constructor, but what's weird is that there truly is a constructor that takes a Graphics instance as a parameter and it doesn't inherit from another class, so I can't think of any other possibilities that can cause this situation.

Furthermore, I have cloned this project to another laptop before I cloned it to this one, and the design time issue didn't exist, so perhaps it's the issue of laptop?

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Application error:

[image: Application Error]

I just viewed the events from Application Error(I only checked the events from .NET Runtime before) and did a rough check. I found that it's basically the problem from `KERNELBASE.dll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out it's a Visual Studio issue, so currently I have nothing to do but rolling back to version 17.8.x of Visual Studio.
See [Mission Planner issue #3306](https://github.com/ArduPilot/MissionPlanner/issues/3306#issue-2175568521).